# for docker that used to work The command `bin/sh` returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/verse

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.8 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev
```

and it fails with `##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.8 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100`

This used to work a couple weeks ago.

Any suggestions how to remedy this?

complete error message:

```
2022-11-10T09:18:40.5040462Z Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.5801563Z Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.5879776Z Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.6 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.5948497Z Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.5954474Z Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.5997954Z Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [480 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.6041090Z Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [761 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.6109038Z Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [580 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.6917686Z Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8476470Z Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1,792 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8636712Z Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8670910Z Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8688797Z Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [528 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8735637Z Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [881 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8808270Z Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.9 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8815528Z Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [944 kB]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8887164Z Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [7,277 B]
2022-11-10T09:18:40.8893189Z Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [3,175 B]
2022-11-10T09:18:41.9120598Z Fetched 24.5 MB in 1s (17.3 MB/s)
2022-11-10T09:18:42.6535417Z Reading package lists...
2022-11-10T09:18:43.4353411Z Reading package lists...
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6303192Z Building dependency tree...
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6304720Z Reading state information...
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6364217Z Package python3.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6364814Z This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6365218Z is only available from another source
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6365378Z 
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6389109Z [91mE: Package 'python3.8' has no installation candidate
2022-11-10T09:18:43.8543258Z [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.8 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
2022-11-10T09:18:43.8608722Z ##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.8 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
2022-11-10T09:18:43.8643823Z ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 100
2022-11-10T09:18:43.8710459Z ##[section]Finishing: Build and push an image to container registry
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete error message?

Comment: updated to include complete error messages

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 3rd line to

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev python3.9 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev
```

and it worked.

Still don't know why 3.8 stopped working though

Comment: As mentioned in the error:

`2022-11-10T09:18:43.6364217Z Package python3.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6364814Z This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
2022-11-10T09:18:43.6365218Z is only available from another source`

The package should've been obsoleted